# Proving that $f(t)=\frac{n^2}{2}\cdot t^{n-4}(1-t^2)\left(t^2-\frac{n-3}{n}\right)$ is bounded above by $1$, for $n\geq6$ and $t\in[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have a problem that looks like a typical problem of maximizing functions in a compact interval. However, I am not being able to prove the bound I need.

> Let $n\geq 6$ be an integer number. Consider the function: $$f(t) = \frac{n^2}{2} \cdot t^{n-4}(1-t^2) \left(t^2 - \frac{n-3}{n}\right) $$
>
> Prove that for all $t\in [0,1]$ it holds $f(t) \leq 1$.

The points where the derivative $f'$ is zero are very ugly expressions.

By maximizing the factor $t^{n-4}(1-t^2)$ and using that the last factor is at most $\frac{3}{n}$ it is possible to deduce that for $n\geq 6$ it is $f(t) \leq \frac{3}{2}$ (in fact, it is possible to bound it in the limit by $\frac{3}{e}\approx 1.1036...$ but that is far from $1$.

I have checked that the claim is true for several random values of $n$ (in fact, I think that the bound can be reduced to something like $0.61...$ for $n>20$ say).

Comment: Thank you for describing your progress! It seems you've used sharp bounds for the two factors separately and that has almost worked. In such situations, the issue is often that those sharp maximums don't happen for the same $t$, so something has been lost. But it can often be improved sufficiently by dividing the interval into two subintervals and using the same procedure on both: if one or the other of the bounds improves on each subinterval, that could be enough.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I think that procedure will work "in theory", but I am not being able to get it. I think that this problem is far from easy or routine. Probably some clever manipulation has to be made (or a rather magic separation into cases).

Comment: For $n=3,t=1/\sqrt3$ I get a value of $\sqrt3$.  When $n$ is large, $t$ has to be near $1$. Call it $t^2=1-u/n$, where $0\le u\le3$, otherwise the whole expression is negative.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I should have written $n\geq 6$. I will fix it now. Both of your remarks are clear to me, but do not yield nothing immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with some clever separation into cases I managed to do it.

- If $1-t^2 < \frac{2}{3n}$ then just bound:
  $$f(t) < \frac{n^2}{2}\cdot 1^{n-4}\cdot \frac{2}{3n} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{n-3}{n}\right) =1.$$
- If $1-t^2 \geq \frac{2}{3n}$, then $t^2\leq 1-\frac{2}{3n}$, so that:
  $$f(t) \leq \frac{n^2}{2} t^{n-4} (1-t^2) \left(1-\frac{2}{3n} - \frac{n-3}{n} \right)= \frac{7n}{6} t^{n-4}(1-t)^2$$
  and the maximum of $t^{n-4}(1-t^2)$ in $[0,1]$ can be found differentiating and equating to zero. It is exactly $\left(1-\frac{2}{n-2}\right)^{\frac{n-4}{2}} \frac{2}{n-2}$. So that, putting al this together:
  $$f(t) \leq \frac{7}{3} \frac{n}{n-2} \left(1 - \frac{2}{n-2}\right)^{\frac{n-4}{2}}.$$
  And as the term in the parentheses tends to $e^{-1} < 0.3679... < 3/7$, it is easy to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

In case a less-clever estimate by separation of cases is useful:

Our goal is to show
$$
\frac{n^{2}}{2}\, t^{n-4}(1 - t^{2}) \left(t^{2} - \frac{n-3}{n}\right)
= \frac{n^{2}}{2}\, t^{n-4}(1 - t^{2}) \left(\frac{3}{n} - (1 - t^{2}\right)
\leq 1
$$
for $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

Write $n = 4 + m$ for $m \geq 2$ and $u = 1 - t^{2}$. The desired inequality becomes
$$
\tfrac{1}{2}(4 + m)^{2}\, (1 - u)^{m/2}\, u(\tfrac{3}{4 + m} - u) \leq 1
$$
for $0 \leq u \leq 1$. Put $c = \frac{3}{4 + m}$ and $v = \frac{u}{c}$, so the desired inequality reads
$$
\tfrac{9}{2}(1 - c v)^{m/2} (v - v^{2}) \leq 1
$$
for $0 \leq v \leq \frac{1}{c}$.

We have $v - v^{2} = \frac{2}{9} - (v - \frac{1}{3})(v - \frac{2}{3}) \leq \frac{2}{9}$ unless $\frac{1}{3} \leq v \leq \frac{2}{3}$. Since $0 \leq 1 - cv \leq 1$, the inequality in this case follows at once.

Otherwise (if $\frac{1}{3} \leq v \leq \frac{2}{3}$), we have $v - v^{2} = \frac{1}{4} - (v - \frac{1}{2})^{2} \leq \frac{1}{4}$ (for all real $v$), while
$$
(1 - cv)^{m/2} \leq (1 - \tfrac{1}{3}c)^{m/2} = (1 - \tfrac{1}{4 + m})^{m/2}.
$$
The right-hand side decreases with $m$, and for $m = 2$ is equal to $\frac{5}{6} < \frac{8}{9}$, so the inequality holds in this case as well.